# Round/Approximate a float number to 3 decimal place in Python pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, decimal, jupyter-notebook

I have a situation where I loaded [this csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Q9hs9vPVB6bDVOdmVGSnlteVE/view?usp=sharing) into pandas DataFrame and sum the values in some of the columns.

The resulting sum was rounded to 3 decimal place for most of the columns except one column (named: **Rise**). How do I round/approximate the sum (which is a float number) to 3 decimal places?

[image: level-book]

I tried the methods listed below in code snippet, the closest rounded the sum to: **0.90200000000000002** instead of **0.902**

Here is what I have tried in Jupyter note:-

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

level_table = pd.read_csv("Level_Book.csv")
level_table.round(3)


BS = level_table["Back Sight"].sum()
FS = level_table["Fore Sight"].sum()
Rise = level_table["Rise"].sum()
Fall = level_table["Fall"].sum()

# I tried the below methods, the closest rounded the sum to: 0.90200000000000002 instead of 0.902
# Rise = np.around(Rise, decimals=3)
# Rise = np.ceil(Rise)
# Rise = np.round(Rise, decimals=3)
# Rise = Rise.apply(np.round())

BS, FS, Rise, Fall
```

**Output =** (4.127, 4.127, 0.90200000000000002, 0.902) or (4.127, 4.127, 0.9019999999999999, 0.902)

**Expected Output =** (4.127, 4.127, 0.902, 0.902)

[image]

Comment: That's a [floating point issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Try `round(Rise, 3)`

Comment: Great @ayhan, that did the magic. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can do this simply by using apply function:

```
sleepstudy['Reaction'] =d['Column'].apply(lambda x: round(x, 3))
```

Answer (score -1):

This was solved by [user2285236](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2285236/user2285236) in a [comment to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812372/round-approximate-a-float-number-to-3-decimal-place-in-python-pandas-dataframe#comment64992383_38812372).

Use the built-in `round` function:

```
round(var_Name, value)
```

- `var_Name` is variable you want to round up and
- `value` is an integer value of decimal places to which you want to round

Example:

```
>>> sum = 6.77765345098888
>>> round(sum, 3)
>>> sum
6.777
```

Comment: This is the solution posted two years ago in a comment to the question, just above your answer. To avoid any smell of plagiarism, it would be quite appropriate to cite this. I'll do this for you.

Comment: Shouldn't that round to 6.778?